# Cannot enable Microsoft Print to PDF once it is disabled

Tags: windows-10, command-line, powershell, print-to-pdf

I used the following command to find the feature name and the second one (Powershell) to disable Microsoft Print to PDF, and the third one to re-enable it.

```
DISM /online /get-features /format:table | find "Disabled"

Disable-WindowsOptionalFeature -Online -FeatureName "Microsoft-Windows-Printing-PrintToPDFServices-Package"

Enable-WindowsOptionalFeature -Online -FeatureName "Microsoft-Windows-Printing-PrintToPDFServices-Package"
```

The disable command works perfectly, however, I get the following message when trying to enable it.

"enable-windowsoptionalfeature : One of several parent features are disabled so current feature can not be enabled." (See Screenshot)

[image: enable-windowsoptionalfeature error]

Secondly, I try to enable the feature through "Turn Windows features On or Off" but it can't be found. (See screenshot)

[image: Turn Windows Features On or Off]

I have researched this for several hours now and the only information I can find is how to add the printer back through Programs and Features. I would appreciate all help resolving this problem.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A Bug has been
[reported](https://social.technet.microsoft.com/Forums/windowsserver/en-US/6d42e97c-686c-4278-b38a-f8d5f18814b5/bug-windows-10-disablewindowsoptionalfeature-deletes-feature-files-without-the-remove-switch?forum=win10itprosetup)
in Windows 10, dating to version 1607, whereby `Disable-WindowsOptionalFeature`
deletes the feature files even though it is supposed to happen only when specifying
the `/Remove` switch. This make it impossible to re-enable the feature by using
`Enable-WindowsOptionalFeature`, since it's simply gone from Windows.

You could try to use the `-All` parameter that may also install any required
parent packages:

```
Enable-WindowsOptionalFeature -online -FeatureName Printing-PrintToPDFServices-Features -All
```

If this does not fix the problem, then
the only solution, until Microsoft fixes this bug (if ever), is
to include a source when you install it again, which should be an extracted
Windows ISO of exactly the same version you are working with.

This might do it:

```
Enable-WindowsOptionalFeature -online -FeatureName Printing-PrintToPDFServices-Features -All -Source "C:\SourceISO\sxs"
```

(Note: I have not tested these commands.)

Comment: Thank you. While the command you provided yielded the same error message, you answered my question as to why this was occurring.